# Modificar un elemento de un array multidimensional asociativo en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array multidimensional que contiene una lista de clientes, cada cliente es un array y en cada cliente hay un campo "points" y quisiera cambiar el valor de "points" sumandole + 10 a cada cliente, para que conserve sus puntos actuales más los 10 extr. Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo?
Esta es una parte del array:

```
  array(30) {
      [0]=>
      array(30) {
       ["first_name"]=>
        string(5) " "
        ["last_name"]=>
        string(8) " "
        ["phone_number"]=>
        string(10) " "
        ["custom_fields"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["company_name"]=>
        string(0) " "
        ["points"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(30) {
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(5) " "
        ["last_name"]=>
        string(8) " "
        ["phone_number"]=>
        string(10) " "
        ["custom_fields"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["company_name"]=>
        string(0) " "
        ["points"]=>
        int(0)
      }
```

Comment: Simplemente debes iterar los "clientes". Puedes usar [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php). También puedes acceder directamente. Por ejemplo: `$clientes[0]['points'] = 999`

Comment: Lo intente con foreach pero el resultado era solo un array con los puntos actuaizados, y necesito que me devuelva el array completo con todos los datos del cliente y con los puntos actualizados, y no puedo realizarlo manualmente ya que el proceso debe ser automatico porque los clientes vienen de una base de datos de un punto de venta

Comment: @ArelyTrujillo ese array es el resultado de un `var_dump`?

Comment: Si, es con var_dump

Comment: @ArelyTrujillo ok, podrías actualizar tu pregunta y adjuntar el array sin `var_dump` porfa

Comment: Estoy trabajando con una api, el array lo obtengo con un get y esta en JSON, y como necesito utilizarlo en mi codigo ocupo un json_decode

Comment: Intente hacerlo con este foreach, pero solo me devuelve el array de los puntos actualizados, no se como hacerlo para que me devuelva el array completo con los puntos actualizados  foreach ($response as &$value) {
        $newpoints[]  = $value['points'] + 10; }

Comment: Aquí estás pasando `$value` por referencia: `&$value` eso es lo que significa la `&` antes de la variable. Entonces, para modificarla sólo tienes que hacer algo así: `$value['points']+=10;`, eso aumentaría en `10` el valor actual de la clave `points` **en el array original, el que estás iterando**, si luego haces un test del array, podrás ver los valores modificados. Aquí en cambio `$newpoints[] = $value['points'] + 10;` lo asignas a una nueva variable que es `$newpoints` en ese caso no tendría sentido pasar por referencia. De todos modos el problema no queda claro en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es otra forma, pero usando el foreach espero que sea de ayuda.

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

if ($array[$key]['points']=='500') {

```
  $array[$key]['points']='700';
  echo "clave cambiada:".$array[$key]['points'];
```

}

}

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Hice un pequeño ejemplo de acuerdo al `var_dump` que tienes.
Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

Mencionas que recibes el `array` en formato `JSON` por lo cual lo tienes que decodificar con `json_decode`. Supongamos que este es tu decodificado:

> **$MiArray = json_decode($arrayJSON, true);**

Una vez decodificado, quieres modificar el objeto `points`, por lo tanto debes recorrer el `array` decodificado, en este caso se usó un `for` para que puedas manipular el numero de `indices` recorrido con la `variable $var` y modificar los objetos.

```
for($var = 0; $var < count($MiArray); $var++) {

   $MiArray[$var]["points"] = 500;
}

print_r($MiArray);
//var_dump($MiArray);
```

Esto modificará todos los objetos con el nombre `points` y les asignará el valor **500**, después de terminar, haces un `var_dump`o `print_r` y verás que el array cuenta con todos los valores junto con los que se modificaron.

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciona perfectamente :D

Comment: No seria mejor implementar `foreach`?